# How can i merge 2 dataframes and their deduction(in case the type is not object)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have 2 dataframes having the same columns and row numbers, some of these data frames columns are Dates(1 per dataframe), others floats and objects where strings are stored.

Let's take the below as a simplified example for df1(my actual dataframe has hundreds of columns):

```
         Date               Val0        Val1       
0   2020-09-29 13:22:57      char1       5.34      
1   2020-09-29 13:23:12      char2       4.5       
2   2020-09-29 13:23:44      char3       Nan      
3   2020-09-29 13:24:01      char4      24
```

`val0` in that example is an object

`df2` looks like:

```
  Date                    Val0        Val1 

     
0   2020-09-29 13:22:58      char6       Nan        
1   2020-09-29 13:23:12      char4       89.77      
2   2020-09-29 13:23:45                  Nan      
3   2020-09-29 13:24:01      char4      24
```

**Expected**

```
      Date                  Date                     Val0     Val0      Val1   Val1  Val1       
0   2020-09-29 13:22:57      2020-09-29 13:22:58    char1   char6       5.34   Nan    5.34         
1   2020-09-29 13:23:12      2020-09-29 13:23:12    char2   char4       4.5   89.77  -85.27             
2   2020-09-29 13:23:44      2020-09-29 13:23:45    char3                Nan    Nan   Nan         
3   2020-09-29 13:24:01      2020-09-29 13:24:01    char4    char4       24     24     0
```

As we can see the floats got deducted and we had a new column having the difference while the objects having the same column are now 'next to one another'

I do realize that having the same column names might not be the approach, example what if we want to drop one or the `.2` added by default by pandas, for me the column names at this stage don't matter they can be whatever as they're aligned as demonstrated and would still help me in my next step when writing to excel which is merging the row names only, example we'd have one   cell with 2 columns under it while it would also be 1 row name of `val1` and 3 columns under it.

```
My code and approach:
```

I wanted to get rid of the stuff i can't deduct, in this case `val0`, so i dropped that column from `df1` and `df2` in copied dataframes then deducted the outcome dfs giving me the last column for val1 and the deduction of dates just in case i wanted it. then concatenated `df1` and `df_2` looking like the below correspondant to `df_6`:

```
df_minus = df_2 - df
    df5 = pd.concat([df_2, df], axis=1)
    df_6 = df5[list(sum(zip(df_2.columns, df.columns), ()))]
    print(df_6)



    Date                  Date                     Val0     Val0      Val1   Val1    
0   2020-09-29 13:22:57      2020-09-29 13:22:58    char1   char6       5.34   Nan          
1   2020-09-29 13:23:12      2020-09-29 13:23:12    char2   char4       4.5   89.77              
2   2020-09-29 13:23:44      2020-09-29 13:23:45    char3                Nan    Nan           
3   2020-09-29 13:24:01      2020-09-29 13:24:01    char4    char4       24     24
```

My approach did solve the columns being objects issue, but then for the floats i though about using df_minus somehow but couldn't find a way.Some might believe i should simply take that column from `df_minus` and add it in `df_6` but let's keep in mind that my actual data has hundreds of column so that's not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that should get you what I think you're trying to do.

We identify numeric columns for which the subtraction operation makes sense, then do the subtraction and use the results to update `df_minus`, a copy of one of the input dataframes. We then rename the columns in `df2` by appending a suffix '.2' and columns in `df_minus` by appending either '.diff' for our subtraction results or '.delete' (marked for future deletion) for all other columns.

We then use your column sorting logic, but with 3 dataframes instead of just 2, so we have `df1`, `df2` and `df_minus` in the results. Finally, we delete the unwanted columns that came from `df_minus`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame([

         {'Date':'2020-09-29 13:22:57','Val0':'char1','Val1':5.34},
         {'Date':'2020-09-29 13:23:12','Val0':'char2','Val1':4.5},
         {'Date':'2020-09-29 13:23:44','Val0':'char3','Val1':np.NaN},
         {'Date':'2020-09-29 13:24:01','Val0':'char4','Val1':24}
])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([

         {'Date':'2020-09-29 13:22:58','Val0':'char6','Val1':np.NaN},
         {'Date':'2020-09-29 13:23:12','Val0':'char4','Val1':89.77},
         {'Date':'2020-09-29 13:23:45','Val0':'',     'Val1':np.NaN},
         {'Date':'2020-09-29 13:24:01','Val0':'char4','Val1':24}
])
print(f"df1:\n{df1}\n")
print(f"df2:\n{df2}\n")

dfNumericCols = set(c for c in df1.columns if isinstance(df1.loc[0,c], (float,int)))
df_minus = df1.copy(deep=True)
df_minus[list(dfNumericCols)] = df1[list(dfNumericCols)] - df2[list(dfNumericCols)]
df_minus.rename(columns={c:c+'.diff' if c in dfNumericCols else c+'.delete' for c in df_minus.columns}, inplace=True)
print(f"df_minus:\n{df_minus}\n")

df2.rename(columns={c:c+'.2' for c in df2.columns}, inplace=True)
df5 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df_minus], axis=1)
df6 = df5[list(sum(zip(df1.columns, df2.columns, df_minus.columns), ()))]
df6 = df6.drop(columns=[c for c in df6 if c[-len('.delete'):] == '.delete'], axis=1)
print(f"df6:\n{df6}\n")
```

Output:

```
df1:
                  Date   Val0   Val1
0  2020-09-29 13:22:57  char1   5.34
1  2020-09-29 13:23:12  char2   4.50
2  2020-09-29 13:23:44  char3    NaN
3  2020-09-29 13:24:01  char4  24.00

df2:
                  Date   Val0   Val1
0  2020-09-29 13:22:58  char6    NaN
1  2020-09-29 13:23:12  char4  89.77
2  2020-09-29 13:23:45           NaN
3  2020-09-29 13:24:01  char4  24.00

df_minus:
           Date.delete Val0.delete  Val1.diff
0  2020-09-29 13:22:57       char1        NaN
1  2020-09-29 13:23:12       char2     -85.27
2  2020-09-29 13:23:44       char3        NaN
3  2020-09-29 13:24:01       char4       0.00

df6:
                  Date               Date.2   Val0 Val0.2   Val1  Val1.2  Val1.diff
0  2020-09-29 13:22:57  2020-09-29 13:22:58  char1  char6   5.34     NaN        NaN
1  2020-09-29 13:23:12  2020-09-29 13:23:12  char2  char4   4.50   89.77     -85.27
2  2020-09-29 13:23:44  2020-09-29 13:23:45  char3           NaN     NaN        NaN
3  2020-09-29 13:24:01  2020-09-29 13:24:01  char4  char4  24.00   24.00       0.00
```